# JavaScript is breaking html-list links

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html-lists, searchbar

When I try to hide my `ul` and `li` when the searchbar is not used, my hyper-links break. I want the searchbar to hide items that don't meet the criteria of what's in the searchbar.

```js
var UL       = document.getElementById("myUL");
var SerInput = document.getElementById("sinput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
SerInput.addEventListener("focus", function() {

});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
SerInput.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  UL.style.display = "none";
});

function MyFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input  = document.getElementById("sinput");
  ul     = document.getElementById("myUL");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  // if the input is empty hide the list
  if (filter.trim().length < 1) {
    ul.style.display = "none";
    return false;
  } else {
    ul.style.display = "block";
  }
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color : rgb(63, 63, 63);
  margin           : 0;
  }
nav {
  background-color : black;
  height           : 56px;
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  }
.nav-left {
  height  : 56px;
  width   : 33%;
  display : inline-block;
  }
.nav-mid {
  height     : 56px;
  width      : 33%;
  display    : inline-block;
  color      : white;
  text-align : center;
  font-size  : 30px;
  }
.nav-right {
  height  : 56px;
  width   : 33%;
  display : inline-block;
  }
#HBtn {
  margin-left  : 25%;
  margin-right : 25%;
  height       : 80%;
  font-weight  : bolder;
  }
#page {
  margin-top : 0;
  }
#search {
  display : inline-block;
  }
div.page-wrapper {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 567px;
  }
div.sidebar {
  width            : 20%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : rgb(35, 35, 35);
  border           : solid 2px black;
  }
#myUL {
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 56px;
  right            : 18%;
  width            : 200px;
  height           : 250px;
  border           : 3px solid black;
  background-color : white;
  overflow         : scroll;
  margin-top       : 0;
  padding          : 0;
  display          : none;
  }
ul.searchlist>li>a {
  list-style      : none;
  text-align      : center;
  margin-top      : 10px;
  text-decoration : none;
  color           : black;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-left">
      <a href="#"><button id="HBtn"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Home</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-mid">
      <p id="page">Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
      <input type="search" id="sinput" placeholder="Search for Names..." autocomplete="off" onkeyup="MyFunction()">
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <ul class="searchlist" id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#"> Adele  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Agnes  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Billy  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Bob    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Calvin </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I know its something within the script because I removed the script and displayed the whole list and it worked. I just want to be able to do the following:

- to display the ul.searchlist when someone is typing in the bar
- to have the links within the ul work when displayed
- to hide the searchbar options that don't match your text when displayed

Comment: what is broken?

Comment: When the search results show up i try and click the text for the link but it just closes the list and does not do anything

Comment: because you hide it on blur

Comment: how do I fix it?